# How to call a function a function where the repetition of a function is redundant

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, linear-transformations

I have a very simple question, yet very hard to Google, so I thought I would ask you guys.

Given a function $f\colon V\rightarrow V$, and given that $f(\vec{v}) = f(f(\vec{v}))$.

What's this property called? I believe it's something from category theory. And what (simple) properties can one derive from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This property is called [**idempotency**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

An idempotent linear map is also called a projection.

If $\Phi:V \to V$ is idempotent, then

> $\ker\Phi \oplus \operatorname{im} \Phi = V$
>
> The only possible eigenvalues of $\Phi$ are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks

Comment: And im $\Phi$ is the space on which everything is "projected" through parallel projection in the direction of ker $\Phi$. This explains the use of the word "projection"

Comment: Haha I actually have to proove this later on

Comment: To complete this answer:
$\operatorname{rank} \Phi = \operatorname{rank}\Phi^2 \iff \Phi \vec{v} = \Phi^2 \vec{v} \iff \ker\Phi \oplus \operatorname{im} \Phi = V$